# Kubuntu taskbar appearing on non-primary monitor, disappears when only one screen enabled

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, amd-graphics

So I recently installed Kubuntu on a PC I custom-built myself, and it has worked fine for the most part. However, it has been having some display issues. I am fairly confident that this is not related to the graphics card, however, I cannot be sure of this.

I recently built a PC. Not the most powerful one, but a powerful one nonetheless. I decided to install Kubuntu on it, as I prefer Kubuntu over Ubuntu, and I have had good experience with Kubuntu in the past. I have 3 monitors, and I set it up to use all 3. It was working fine, until a few minutes ago. The taskbar (and everything on it, including the application launcher) was moved to a monitor that was not my primary. If I made the monitor that had the taskbar the primary monitor, the taskbar would revert to being on my main monitor, even though my main monitor is not the primary.

Rebooting the computer does not help, neither does restarting the plasma desktop entirely. If I only leave one monitor enabled/plugged in, then it becomes the primary, and the taskbar is not available on it.

From my limited analysis, it seems that the taskbar is set to go onto a non-primary monitor. I do not believe that it is set to only go onto one specific monitor, because by changing what is primary and what is enabled, I can get the taskbar onto any monitor I have connected to my computer, unless the monitor is primary.

**Computer Specifications:**

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-core

GPU: AMD Radeon RX 5600 XT

RAM: 16GB

Motherboard: Gigabyte A320M-H Socket AM4 mATX

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.10

If there is any more information you would like me to provide to assist you in solving this issue, I would be happy to help.

Thanks,

VoxelTek

EDIT:I figured out a solution! Scroll down to find the answer.

Answer (score 3):

By editing the panel (right click) you can drag the "Screen edge" over to whatever monitor you wish for the taskbar to be on.

Comment: Kubuntu 22.04: Indeed, it seems the taskbar is not attached to the primary screen permanently. It seems this can be configured. It happened randomly to me. Fortunately, as mentioned here, it can be fixed by RMB on the taskbar -> Enter Edit Mode -> Drag it back to the primary screen.

Answer (score 0):

So you say that the expected behavior should be that the taskbar appears on the primary monitor? I'm not certain that KDE guarantees that behavior. Maybe your best bet here is to configure which monitor is your primary monitor such that the taskbar lands wherever you want it to be.